# APPLICATION FAILED TO START how to fix?

Tags: spring

```
Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 9009 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:
Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 9009, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I get an error of this kind, but I have not changed the port, what should I do in this case?
I can throw application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you would like to check application running on that port please either do netstat command or resmon.exe and if application is user then exit it.

Or start appliation with new port number